# Get Azure DevOps service connection service principal id with powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-automation, serviceconnection

I am working on automating Azure Active Directory App Registrations and Azure Devops Service Connections, and have hit a wall.

I want to query Azure DevOps service connections (service endpoints) by Service Principal ID (or at least get the id). This is possible when using Azure CLI:

```
az devops service-endpoint list --query "[?authorization.parameters.serviceprincipalid=='xxx']"
```

But since I am running this in Azure automation account as a powershell runbook, the Azure CLI is not supported.

Then I tried the Azure DevOps REST API, and called it from powershell, but the response does not contain the service principal ID, but just this:

```
authorization : @{parameters=; scheme=ServicePrincipal}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

**UPDATE**

I am calling the rest API like this:

```
$uriAccount = $UriOrg + "_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?endpointNames={name}&api-version=6.1-preview.4"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriAccount -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader
```

And $result.value gives me this:

```
authorization : @{parameters=; scheme=ServicePrincipal}
```

Comment: Hi there, please check whether my answer below can help you. If not, could you edit your question and provide which REST API you are using so that people can further investigate the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the REST API [Endpoints - Get Service Endpoints By Names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/get%20service%20endpoints%20by%20names?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?endpointNames={endpointNames}&api-version=6.0-preview.4
```

In this REST API, you can find the id and details by the name of a service connection.

Here is an example to use the REST API in PowerShell:

```
$token = "{pat}"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$url="https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?endpointNames={endpointNames}&api-version=6.0-preview.4"
$head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method GET -Headers $head
```

**Update:**

The cause for this question is that you output `result` in the wrong way.

For JSON response bodies, there is no intuitive way to get results without specifying the final layer.
Here is my modified code, notice how I print `result`:

```
$token = "{pat}"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$url="https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?endpointNames={endpointNames}&api-version=6.0-preview.4"
$head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
$reslut = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method GET -Headers $head
echo $result.value.authorization.parameters
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I updated the post. Your suggestion gave me the same result.

Comment: @Hush Your updates are helpful! I have updates my answer~

Comment: You are my new favorite person! Thank you!