# Azure Devops > How to retrieve Service Connection information with powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-devops-server-2019

Good morning Azure expert,

I configured a **service connexion** with Azure cloud environment in my Azure DevOps server like below
[image]

Then in my release I have a Powershell script which need to retrieve some information like TenantID/ SP id / SP secret / Subscription ID.

I do not want to create release **variable** to avoid duplication.

I'm pretty sure these variables could be retrieve with powershell but I have totally no idea on how to do it. Do you have any idea - suggestions - recommendation ?

Regards,
Terry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below script to get the service connection details which will use the RestAPI,

For example:

```
$token = "{pat}"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$url="https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?endpointNames={endpointNames}&api-version=6.0-preview.4"
$head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method GET -Headers $head
```

- ***SOURCE***| [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65513609/get-azure-devops-service-connection-service-principal-id-with-powershell) as suggested by @*Jane Ma-MSFT*.

For more information please refer the below links:

- [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENT|Manage service connections***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)
- [***Developer Community|Get ftp service connection credentials from Powershell in Azure DevOps***](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/get-ftp-service-connection-credentials-from-powers/458690)

Comment: wonderful AjayKumarGhose-MT! I did find the thread you indicated when i wrote my question. I probably used the wrong keyword. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad to be of help :)